# Anime or manga with a girl who can draw the future.

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

I remember the anime/manga had a girl attending a high school and she's an artist. She gets some kind of magic hand and can draw the future. But the drawing is very obscure.

I remember her "falling" into the drawing. It had a male student on a cliff, toys behind him, and a huge money wall across from the cliff, and the male student's father behind the wall was as big as a Titan. So the girl befriends him and finds out that his dad doesn't care about him or is disappointed in him or something.

I remember the male student wanting to jump in front of a train but the girl stops him before he takes the step.

Comment: This question is about an anime or manga that has a "magic hand" and a person '"falling" into [a] drawing", which sounds fantastical. As such, I have migrated it here.